# MPMoviePlayerController blocking the Main Thread

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller, audio-streaming

I am using the `MPMoviePlayerController(MPMPC)` to stream audio into an application and thats working really fine. Just with one exception, during low network connectivity the app becomes unresponsive.

Now I have even tried to use `AVPlayer` too but with more or less same experience. And for some reason I cannot find any issues related to this on the internet. So I am not sure if this is from my end or is it how `MPMoviePlayerController` behaves during low connectivity.

I even tried to log any function that is being called after giving `URL` to the `MPMPC` but none of the functions are called.

I have used below three notification to get events of the MPMPC

```
MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification
```

Comment: did you check status of MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK

Comment: @Robin Hi, I use MPM with collection view - after play method the main thread blocked for 2 seconds.. any new solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the available networking bandwidth is becoming too low to keep up proper playback, `MPMoviePlayerController` will trigger the  `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` and the `loadState` will have `MPMovieLoadStateStalled` set.

You may then mask the load-state within your notification handler and run any actions needed by your app for this state:

```
if ((movieController_.loadState & MPMovieLoadStateStalled) == MPMovieLoadStateStalled)
{
   NSLog(@"playback stalled - make sure we don't block now!");
}
```

Once the player has recovered, once again the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` is triggered and the `loadState` property will have the bits for `MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK` set:

```
if ((movieController_.loadState & MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK) == MPMovieLoadStatePlaythroughOK)
{
   NSLog(@"playback should run uninterrupted from now on.");
}
```

However, I never experienced any interface slowdowns of my app caused by the `MPMovieLoadStateStalled` state. I'ld say that must be your code acting weird, it is not `MPMoviePlayerController` as I know it. Additionally, those notifications are always sent, I never experienced scenarios in which they were not properly triggered.

I can only recommend to recreate this issue within a minimal test-case and work your way up from that one towards your app (possibly from both sides, test-case and your app).

For simulating bandwidth breakdowns, I would recommend using [Charles proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/).

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I even tried to use AVPlayer for that matter and tried to log all the methods that was been called when the player gets the url .But I cannot see any other function call logging in after. Also in a good network the same application works very smoothly.

Comment: Also I was wondering that is it possible that the URL length a matter? Cause the url I gave to a player is very big.

Comment: @Till I see that MPMovieLoadStateStalled is never called

Comment: @onmyway133 Do you mean that your notification handler for `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` is never called with the `loadState` having `MPMovieLoadStateStalled` set even though the networking bandwidth has become too small to keep up playback? Please clarify your comment.

Comment: @Till yes, have you met that problem ?

Comment: @onmyway133 No, never encountered such issue. I would suggest you double-check your notification handler registration and to use a limiting proxy for simulating as described in my answer.

Comment: @Till and for stimulating bandwidth, iOS can do it in the Settings